# How to get row count of ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, objectdatasource, rowcount

Hello you all

How can i get row count of ObjectDataSouce ?

I use ObjectDataSource and DataList . I want show some thing to the user for example in a label when there are certain row returned by ObjectDataSource . One of situation is when there is no record .

Thank you .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking for the same answer... Another solution I ended up using is the following:
This is found on a .vb file behind an .aspx page. It handles the "selected" event of the datasource.

```
Protected Sub ObjectDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles ObjectDataSource1.Selected
    ' Select data for rowcount
    Dim dt As DataTable = e.ReturnValue
    ' Set row count label
    Me.lblCount.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

The `ObjectDataSource` does not have a direct way to get the total row count. One of the reasons for this is that if all you want is the total row count then you don't need the data source at all! To get the row count just talk to your Business Logic Layer (BLL) and get the total rows:

```
MyBLL bll = new MyBLL();
int customerRowCount = bll.Customers.GetRowCount();
```

The `ObjectDataSource` does have a `SelectCountMethod` that can be used when data bound controls such as the `GridView` need to access the total row count. However, this is only used while also performing a Select operation. That is, there is no way to *only* get the row count. The row count is only used so that the data bound control can display a pager control - it is not used for anything else.

Answer (score 6):

Found this [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/995482.aspx):

```
bool bGetSelectCount;
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (bGetSelectCount)
        TextBox1.Text = e.ReturnValue.ToString(); 
}

protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    bGetSelectCount = e.ExecutingSelectCount;
}
```

Comment: You inspired a simpler solution for my application:

    private void MyObjectDataSource_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            var count = e.ReturnValue as int?;
            this.litHitCount.Text = (!count.HasValue || count.Value == 0) ? ""
                                : (count == 1) ? "1 hit"
                                : $"{count} hits";
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this very simply using a pager template e.g.

```
       <asp:DataPager PagedControlID="PagedControlId" PageSize="20" QueryStringField="QueryStringName" ID="InfoPager" runat="server">
           <Fields>
               <asp:TemplatePagerField>
                   <PagerTemplate>
                        Showing results 
                        <%=InfoPager.StartRowIndex + 1 %> 
                        to 
                        <%= (new []{(InfoPager.StartRowIndex + InfoPager.PageSize),InfoPager.TotalRowCount})
                                      .OrderBy(x => x)
                                      .First()%> 
                        of 
                        <%=InfoPager.TotalRowCount %>
                   </PagerTemplate>
               </asp:TemplatePagerField>
           </Fields>
       </asp:DataPager>
```

This will produce the text "Results x to y of z" including a check for the last page.

Cheers,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub objItemsList_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles objItemsList.Selected
    lblMessage.Text = DirectCast(e.ReturnValue, DataTable).Rows.Count & " record(s) found"
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the ObjectDatasource is a dataset, so I get row number in objectdatasource_selected event like this

```
e.ReturnValue.tables(0).rows.count.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub myODS_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles myODS.Selected
    Dim s As String = e.ReturnValue.ToString
    Dim rows As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(s, rows)

    'rows variable now holds the total number of results, not just what's displayed on the current gridview page
End Sub
```